# How to programmatically set registry setting to prevent Outlook from removing the VSTO Addin

Tags: outlook, vsto, outlook-addin

Hi is there a way to programatically set the following registry key:

`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Outlook\Resiliency\DoNotDisableAddinList\`

with `DWORD= 1`

As I learned from this posting (among many others) this prevents Outlook from removing my Addin from Outlook for being slow. Yes, it would be better to design the AddIn for being faster. But as it needs to connect service on the internet this will be hard to achieve. BTW: I have this problem also with many other Addins.

Comment: Are you accessing a web server synchronously on the main thread while Outlook is starting up? That is a really bad idea...

Answer (score 0):

You need to use .Net base class libraries to get the job done, the [RegistryKey](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.registrykey?view=netframework-4.8) class represents a key-level node in the Windows registry. See [How to: Create a Key In the Registry (Visual C#)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/file-system/how-to-create-a-key-in-the-registry) for more information.

Read more about possible windows registry keys and their values in the [Add-ins are user re-enabled after being disabled by Office programs](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2758876/add-ins-are-user-re-enabled-after-being-disabled-by-office-programs) article.